# What is the correct way to write this function?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was making a program where first parameter is a list and second parameter is a list of dictionaries. I want to return a list of lists like this:

As an example, if this were a function call:

```
make_lists(['Example'], 
           [{'Example': 'Made-up', 'Extra Keys' : 'Possible'}]
)
```

the expected return value would be:

```
[ ['Made-up'] ]
```

As an second example, if this were a function call:

```
make_lists(['Hint', 'Num'],
           [{'Hint': 'Length 2 Not Required', 'Num' : 8675309},
            {'Num': 1, 'Hint' : 'Use 1st param order'}]
)
```

the expected return value would be:

```
[ ['Length 2 Not Required', 8675309],    
  ['Use 1st param order', 1] 
]
```

I have written a code for this but my code does not return a list of lists, it just returns a single list. Please can someone explain?

```
def make_lists(s,lod):
  a = []
  lol =[]
  i = 0
  for x in lod:
      for y in x:
        for k in s:
          if(y==k):
            lol.append(x.get(y))
            i = i+1
  return lol
```

Expected Output:

```
[ ['Length 2 Not Required', 8675309],['Use 1st param order', 1] ]
```

Output:

```
['Length 2 Not Required', 8675309, 1, 'Use 1st param order']
```

Comment: What is the `a` list for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - I've managed to modify your existing code slighty, and added explanation in the comments. Essentially, you just need to use a sub-list and add that to the master list `lol`, and then in each loop iteration over elements in `lod`, append to the sub-list instead of the outermost list.

```py
def make_lists(s,lod):
  a = []
  lol =[]
  i = 0
  for x in lod:
      ## Added
      # Here we want to create a new list, and add it as a sub-list
      # within 'lol'
      lols = []
      lol.append(lols)
      ## Done
      for y in x:
        for k in s:
          if(y==k):
            # Changed 'lol' to 'lols' here
            lols.append(x.get(y))
            i = i+1
  return lol


print(make_lists(['Example'], [{'Example': 'Made-up', 'Extra Keys' : 'Possible'}]))
print(make_lists(['Hint', 'Num'], [{'Hint': 'Length 2 Not Required', 'Num' : 8675309}, {'Num': 1, 'Hint' : 'Use 1st param order'}]))
```

Prints:

```
[['Made-up']]
[['Length 2 Not Required', 8675309], [1, 'Use 1st param order']]
```

#### A simpler solution

For a cleaner (and potentially more efficient approach), I'd suggest using builtins like `map` and using a `list` comprehension to tackle this problem:

```py
def make_lists(s, lod):
    return [[*map(dict_obj.get, s)] for dict_obj in lod]
```

But note, that this approach includes elements as `None` in cases where the desired keys in `s` are not present in the dictionary objects within the list `lod`.

To work around that, you can pass the result of `map` to the `filter` builtin function so that `None` values (which represent missing keys in dictionaries) are then stripped out in the result:

```py
def make_lists(s, lod):
    return [[*filter(None, map(dict_obj.get, s))] for dict_obj in lod]


print(make_lists(['Example'], [{'Extra Keys' : 'Possible'}]))
print(make_lists(['Hint', 'Num'], [{'Num' : 8675309}, {'Num': 1, 'Hint' : 'Use 1st param order'}]))
```

Output:

```
[[]]
[[8675309], ['Use 1st param order', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of dictionaries, is that you can access them by key:

```
def make_lists(keys, dicts):
   result = []
   for d in dicts:
      vals = [d[k] for k in keys if k in d]
      if len(vals) > 0:
          result.append(vals)
   return result
```

Let's have a look what happens here:

We still have the `result` array, which accumulates the answers, but now it's called `result` instead of `lol`

Next we iterate through every dictionary:

```
for d in dicts:
```

For each dictionary `d`, we create a list, which is a lookup in that dictionary for the keys in `keys`, if the key `k` is in the dictionary `d`:

```
vals = [d[k] for k in keys if k in d]
```

The specs don't detail this, but I assume if none of the keys are in the dictionary, you don't want it added to the array. For that, we have a check if `vals` have any results, and only then we add it to the results:

```
if len(vals) > 0:
    result.append(vals)
```